# Initialize a container inside a class/struct with std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I never was really able to work with `std::initializer_list`, and I'd like to change that. So I'm trying to do this really simple thing, which is to forward the initializer list to initialize a struct member. I tried a lot of things, but there is a example :

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

struct Foo
{
    using U_Func = std::function<void()>;
    using U_MapFunc = std::unordered_map<std::string, U_Func>;

    U_MapFunc  funcMap;

    Foo(std::initializer_list<U_MapFunc::value_type> mapParams)
        : funcMap(mapParams)
    {}
};

Foo test(
    {"", []() {}}
);
```

Someone can tell me how I should write this code?

Comment: Question like "Someone can tell me how I should write this code?" will be closed very soon. This page http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list is all you want.

Comment: @liliscent: Nothing on that page will point out the bug in this code.

Comment: @liliscent well I didn't intend to keep this question anyway ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was expecting this too be so stupid that it would have some duplicate I didn't find or things like that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Don't worry, I searched until the moment when the links that duckduckgo gave me wasn't revelant and even on Stackoverflow directly. That was just a feeling ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically not much more than a typo.

You only provided one `value_type` in the initializer_list, but it is supposed to be, well, a *list* of `value_type`s. So, add another set of braces:

```
Foo test(
  {{"", []() {}}}
);
```

Or write it like this for added clarity:

```
Foo test{
    // Element list under here
    {
        // One element here
        {"", []() {}}
    }
};
```

The resulting `std::initializer_list` can be copied (though the things inside it won't be copied) so your "forwarding" works just fine.

Comment: Seems like the first version isn't working on VS, which is why I was a bit lost (Yeah I removed  too much brackets for the example sorry!)

Comment: _Seems like the first version isn't working on VS_ Works for me in VS2017 without problems